# What does the copy_initial_weights documentation mean in the higher library for Pytorch?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I was trying to use the higher library for meta-learning and I was having issues understanding what the `copy_initial_weights` mean. The docs say:

> copy_initial_weights – if true, the weights of the patched module are copied to form the initial weights of the patched module, and thus are not part of the gradient tape when unrolling the patched module. If this is set to False, the actual module weights will be the initial weights of the patched module. This is useful when doing MAML, for example.

but that doesn't make much sense to me because of the following:

For example, "the weights of the patched module are copied to form the initial weights of the patched module" doesn't make sense to me because when the context manager is initiated a patched module does not exist yet. So it is unclear what we are copying from and to where (and why copying is something we want to do).

Also, "unrolling the patched module" does not make sense to me. We usually unroll a computaiton graph caused by a for loop. A patched module is just a neural net that has been modified by this library. Unrolling is ambiguous.

Also, there isn't a technical definition for "gradient tape".

Also, when describing what false is, saying that it's useful for MAML isn't actually useful because it doesn't even hint why it's useful for MAML.

Overall, it's impossible to use the context manager.

Any explanations and examples of what the that flag does in more precise terms would be really valuable.

---

Related:

- gitissue: https://github.com/facebookresearch/higher/issues/30
- new gitissue: https://github.com/facebookresearch/higher/issues/54
- pytorch forum: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/why-does-maml-need-copy-initial-weights-false/70387
- pytorch forum: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/what-does-copy-initial-weights-do-in-the-higher-library/70384
- important question related to this on how the fmodel parameters are copied so that the optimizers work (and the use of deep copy): [Why does higher need to deep copy the parameters of the base model to create a functional model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62437960/why-does-higher-need-to-deep-copy-the-parameters-of-the-base-model-to-create-a-f#62438602)

Comment: time to answer your own question https://github.com/facebookresearch/higher/issues/30#issuecomment-594470306

Comment: @eusoubrasileiro I am trying but it's still not clear to me. To see my latest discussion on the new wording of the docs check: https://github.com/facebookresearch/higher/issues/54

Comment: @eusoubrasileiro my current answer (will accept an answer and post my own once I am 100% sure it's right) is the following: 1) when `copy_initial_weights` is True the higher library makes a `clone()` and `detach()` copy of the modules parameters given at the start of the inner context. It means that there will be no gradient flow due to the detach (so the original one's aren't trained) and the clone makes them safer to use with in-place ops.

Comment: @eusoubrasileiro When `copy_initial_weights=False` it only does a `.clone()`. The clone keeps the gradient history so the original parameters are trainable. But the clone disallows changes to the original parameters directly making it safer to use when doing in-place ops (e.g. you can't overwrite the memory values of tensors that autograd would use to compute any backward pass). The gradients flow to the original parameters because that's how clone works so you are training the **initialization of your base model** (i.e. the initial weights of the base model).

Comment: @eusoubrasileiro Note you still need to set `tracking_higher_grads=True` since the docs say `if True, during unrolled optimization the graph be retained, and the fast weights will bear grad funcs, so as to permit backpropagation through the optimization process` basically meaning the fast weights (i.e. `fnet.parameters(T=t)`) will have gradient functions thus it allows to connect the forward pass into a computation graph that is able to perform backprop correctly.

Comment: Is`copy_initial_weights = True` during meta-testing safe? Or what should be the value in meta-testing?

Answer (score 2):

**Short version**

Call to `higher.innerloop_ctx` with `model` as argument create temporary patched model and unrolled optimizer for that model: `(fmodel, diffopt)`. It is expected that in the inner loop fmodel will iteratively receive some input, compute output and loss and then `diffopt.step(loss)` will be called. Each time `diffopt.step` is called `fmodel` will create next version of parameters `fmodel.parameters(time=T)` which is a new tensor computed using previous ones (with the full graph allowing to compute gradients through the process). If at any point user calls `backward` on any tensor, regular pytorch gradient computation/accumulation will start in a way allowing gradients to propagate to e.g. optimizer's parameters (such as `lr`, `momentum` - if they were passed as tensors requiring gradients to `higher.innerloop_ctx` using `override`).

Creation-time version of `fmodel`'s parameters `fmodel.parameters(time=0)` is a copy of original `model` parameters. If `copy_initial_weights=True` provided (default) then `fmodel.parameters(time=0)` will be a `clone`+`detach`'ed version of `model`'s parameters (i.e. will preserve values, but will severe all connections to the original model). If `copy_initial_weights=False` provided, then `fmodel.parameters(time=0)` will be `clone`'d version of `model`'s parameters and thus will allow gradients to propagate to original `model`'s parameters (see [pytorch doc](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html?highlight=clone#torch.Tensor.clone) on `clone`).

**Terminology clarifications**

- *gradient tape* here is referring to the graph pytorch uses to go through computations to propagate gradients to all leaf tensors requiring gradients. If at some point you cut the link to some leaf tensor requiring parameters (e.g. how it is done for `fnet.parameters()` for `copy_initial_weights=True` case) then the original `model.parameters()` won't be "on gradient tape" anymore for your `meta_loss.backward()` computation.
- *unrolling the patched module* here refers to the part of `meta_loss.backward()` computation when pytorch is going through all `fnet.parameters(time=T)` starting from the latest and ending with the earliest (`higher` doesn't control the process - this is just regular pytorch gradient computation, `higher` is just in charge of how these new `time=T` parameters are being created from previous ones each time `diffopt.step` is called and how `fnet` is always using the latest ones for forward computation).

**Long version**

Let's start from the beginning. Main functionality (only functionality, really) of `higher` library is unrolling of a model's parameter optimization in a differentiable manner. It can come either in the form of directly using differentiable optimizer through e.g. `higher.get_diff_optim` as in [this example](https://github.com/facebookresearch/higher/blob/master/examples/deep-energy-mnist.py) or in the form of `higher.innerloop_ctx` as in [this example](https://github.com/facebookresearch/higher/blob/master/examples/maml-omniglot.py).

The option with `higher.innerloop_ctx` is wrapping the creation of "stateless" model `fmodel` from existing  model for you and gives you an "optimizer" `diffopt` for this `fmodel`. So as summarized in the README.md of higher it allows you to switch from:

```
model = MyModel()
opt = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters())

for xs, ys in data:
    opt.zero_grad()
    logits = model(xs)
    loss = loss_function(logits, ys)
    loss.backward()
    opt.step()
```

to

```
model = MyModel()
opt = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters())

with higher.innerloop_ctx(model, opt) as (fmodel, diffopt):
    for xs, ys in data:
        logits = fmodel(xs)  # modified `params` can also be passed as a kwarg
        loss = loss_function(logits, ys)  # no need to call loss.backwards()
        diffopt.step(loss)  # note that `step` must take `loss` as an argument!

    # At the end of your inner loop you can obtain these e.g. ...
    grad_of_grads = torch.autograd.grad(
        meta_loss_fn(fmodel.parameters()), fmodel.parameters(time=0))
```

The difference between training `model` and doing `diffopt.step` to update `fmodel` is that `fmodel` is not updating the parameters in-place as `opt.step()` in the original part would do. Instead each time `diffopt.step` is called new versions of parameters are created in such a way, that `fmodel` would use new ones for the next step, but all previous ones are still preserved.

I.e. `fmodel` starts with only `fmodel.parameters(time=0)` available, but after you called `diffopt.step` N times you can ask `fmodel` to give you `fmodel.parameters(time=i)` for any `i` up to `N` inclusive. Notice that `fmodel.parameters(time=0)` doesn't change in this process at all, just every time `fmodel` is applied to some input it will use the latest version of parameters it currently has.

Now, what exactly is `fmodel.parameters(time=0)`? It is created [here](https://github.com/facebookresearch/higher/blob/master/higher/patch.py#L523) and depends on `copy_initial_weights`. If `copy_initial_weights==True` then `fmodel.parameters(time=0)` are `clone`'d and `detach`'ed parameters of `model`. Otherwise they are only `clone`'d, but not `detach`'ed!

That means that when we do meta-optimization step, the original `model`'s parameters will actually accumulate gradients if and only if `copy_initial_weights==False`. And in MAML we want to optimize `model`'s starting weights so we actually do need to get gradients from meta-optimization step.

I think one of the issues here is that `higher` lack of simpler toy examples to demonstrate what is going on, instead rushing to show more serious things as the examples. So let me try to fill that gap here and demonstrate what is going on using the simplest toy example I could come up with (model with 1 weight which multiplies input by that weight):

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import higher
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1)
torch.manual_seed(3)
N = 100
actual_multiplier = 3.5
meta_lr = 0.00001
loops = 5 # how many iterations in the inner loop we want to do

x = torch.tensor(np.random.random((N,1)), dtype=torch.float64) # features for inner training loop
y = x * actual_multiplier # target for inner training loop
model = nn.Linear(1, 1, bias=False).double() # simplest possible model - multiple input x by weight w without bias
meta_opt = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=meta_lr, momentum=0.)


def run_inner_loop_once(model, verbose, copy_initial_weights):
    lr_tensor = torch.tensor([0.3], requires_grad=True)
    momentum_tensor = torch.tensor([0.5], requires_grad=True)
    opt = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.3, momentum=0.5)
    with higher.innerloop_ctx(model, opt, copy_initial_weights=copy_initial_weights, override={'lr': lr_tensor, 'momentum': momentum_tensor}) as (fmodel, diffopt):
        for j in range(loops):
            if verbose:
                print('Starting inner loop step j=={0}'.format(j))
                print('    Representation of fmodel.parameters(time={0}): {1}'.format(j, str(list(fmodel.parameters(time=j)))))
                print('    Notice that fmodel.parameters() is same as fmodel.parameters(time={0}): {1}'.format(j, (list(fmodel.parameters())[0] is list(fmodel.parameters(time=j))[0])))
            out = fmodel(x)
            if verbose:
                print('    Notice how `out` is `x` multiplied by the latest version of weight: {0:.4} * {1:.4} == {2:.4}'.format(x[0,0].item(), list(fmodel.parameters())[0].item(), out[0].item()))
            loss = ((out - y)**2).mean()
            diffopt.step(loss)

        if verbose:
            # after all inner training let's see all steps' parameter tensors
            print()
            print("Let's print all intermediate parameters versions after inner loop is done:")
            for j in range(loops+1):
                print('    For j=={0} parameter is: {1}'.format(j, str(list(fmodel.parameters(time=j)))))
            print()

        # let's imagine now that our meta-learning optimization is trying to check how far we got in the end from the actual_multiplier
        weight_learned_after_full_inner_loop = list(fmodel.parameters())[0]
        meta_loss = (weight_learned_after_full_inner_loop - actual_multiplier)**2
        print('  Final meta-loss: {0}'.format(meta_loss.item()))
        meta_loss.backward() # will only propagate gradient to original model parameter's `grad` if copy_initial_weight=False
        if verbose:
            print('  Gradient of final loss we got for lr and momentum: {0} and {1}'.format(lr_tensor.grad, momentum_tensor.grad))
            print('  If you change number of iterations "loops" to much larger number final loss will be stable and the values above will be smaller')
        return meta_loss.item()

print('=================== Run Inner Loop First Time (copy_initial_weights=True) =================\n')
meta_loss_val1 = run_inner_loop_once(model, verbose=True, copy_initial_weights=True)
print("\nLet's see if we got any gradient for initial model parameters: {0}\n".format(list(model.parameters())[0].grad))

print('=================== Run Inner Loop Second Time (copy_initial_weights=False) =================\n')
meta_loss_val2 = run_inner_loop_once(model, verbose=False, copy_initial_weights=False)
print("\nLet's see if we got any gradient for initial model parameters: {0}\n".format(list(model.parameters())[0].grad))

print('=================== Run Inner Loop Third Time (copy_initial_weights=False) =================\n')
final_meta_gradient = list(model.parameters())[0].grad.item()
# Now let's double-check `higher` library is actually doing what it promised to do, not just giving us
# a bunch of hand-wavy statements and difficult to read code.
# We will do a simple SGD step using meta_opt changing initial weight for the training and see how meta loss changed
meta_opt.step()
meta_opt.zero_grad()
meta_step = - meta_lr * final_meta_gradient # how much meta_opt actually shifted inital weight value
meta_loss_val3 = run_inner_loop_once(model, verbose=False, copy_initial_weights=False)

meta_loss_gradient_approximation = (meta_loss_val3 - meta_loss_val2) / meta_step

print()
print('Side-by-side meta_loss_gradient_approximation and gradient computed by `higher` lib: {0:.4} VS {1:.4}'.format(meta_loss_gradient_approximation, final_meta_gradient))
```

Which produces this output:

```
=================== Run Inner Loop First Time (copy_initial_weights=True) =================

Starting inner loop step j==0
    Representation of fmodel.parameters(time=0): [tensor([[-0.9915]], dtype=torch.float64, requires_grad=True)]
    Notice that fmodel.parameters() is same as fmodel.parameters(time=0): True
    Notice how `out` is `x` multiplied by the latest version of weight: 0.417 * -0.9915 == -0.4135
Starting inner loop step j==1
    Representation of fmodel.parameters(time=1): [tensor([[-0.1217]], dtype=torch.float64, grad_fn=<AddBackward0>)]
    Notice that fmodel.parameters() is same as fmodel.parameters(time=1): True
    Notice how `out` is `x` multiplied by the latest version of weight: 0.417 * -0.1217 == -0.05075
Starting inner loop step j==2
    Representation of fmodel.parameters(time=2): [tensor([[1.0145]], dtype=torch.float64, grad_fn=<AddBackward0>)]
    Notice that fmodel.parameters() is same as fmodel.parameters(time=2): True
    Notice how `out` is `x` multiplied by the latest version of weight: 0.417 * 1.015 == 0.4231
Starting inner loop step j==3
    Representation of fmodel.parameters(time=3): [tensor([[2.0640]], dtype=torch.float64, grad_fn=<AddBackward0>)]
    Notice that fmodel.parameters() is same as fmodel.parameters(time=3): True
    Notice how `out` is `x` multiplied by the latest version of weight: 0.417 * 2.064 == 0.8607
Starting inner loop step j==4
    Representation of fmodel.parameters(time=4): [tensor([[2.8668]], dtype=torch.float64, grad_fn=<AddBackward0>)]
    Notice that fmodel.parameters() is same as fmodel.parameters(time=4): True
    Notice how `out` is `x` multiplied by the latest version of weight: 0.417 * 2.867 == 1.196

Let's print all intermediate parameters versions after inner loop is done:
    For j==0 parameter is: [tensor([[-0.9915]], dtype=torch.float64, requires_grad=True)]
    For j==1 parameter is: [tensor([[-0.1217]], dtype=torch.float64, grad_fn=<AddBackward0>)]
    For j==2 parameter is: [tensor([[1.0145]], dtype=torch.float64, grad_fn=<AddBackward0>)]
    For j==3 parameter is: [tensor([[2.0640]], dtype=torch.float64, grad_fn=<AddBackward0>)]
    For j==4 parameter is: [tensor([[2.8668]], dtype=torch.float64, grad_fn=<AddBackward0>)]
    For j==5 parameter is: [tensor([[3.3908]], dtype=torch.float64, grad_fn=<AddBackward0>)]

  Final meta-loss: 0.011927987982895929
  Gradient of final loss we got for lr and momentum: tensor([-1.6295]) and tensor([-0.9496])
  If you change number of iterations "loops" to much larger number final loss will be stable and the values above will be smaller

Let's see if we got any gradient for initial model parameters: None

=================== Run Inner Loop Second Time (copy_initial_weights=False) =================

  Final meta-loss: 0.011927987982895929

Let's see if we got any gradient for initial model parameters: tensor([[-0.0053]], dtype=torch.float64)

=================== Run Inner Loop Third Time (copy_initial_weights=False) =================

  Final meta-loss: 0.01192798770078706

Side-by-side meta_loss_gradient_approximation and gradient computed by `higher` lib: -0.005311 VS -0.005311
```

Comment: Just to make it 100% clear - the `meta_opt` step in the toy example here is not what MAML does, it's just using same mechanism of getting gradient through meta loss.

Comment: hey Alex, sorry for not saying anything. I was trying to understand your answer but then found that higher does `p.clone()` when I `copy_initial_weights = False`, which confused me. I guess my main confusion right now is that I don't understand `.clone()` and been reading about it all day. Perhaps you can help. Why is that the correct thing to do? I would have assumed that if it's **not copying** then it would **not be cloning** but that's not what's happening and ended up confusing me. Do you know what's going on?

Comment: I understand how this is confusing - in fact this is the only place I can remember where I saw `clone` is used without `detach` (other way around is more common for `stop_gradient` style things). Now here is the cloning is actually not strictly needed in my opinion (i.e. `higher` could have just used exactly same tensor, not a cloned version for the case with `copy_initial_weights=False`). It looks like cloning here is just done as an extra precaution in case that user for some reason starts in-place modifying patched network parameters which is not really expected use case.

Comment: So `clone` here is copying the values, but also leaving intact the link for gradient computation. I.e. when any gradients reach `fnet.parameters(time=0)` they will also be accumulated in original model's parameter tensors `model.parameters()` - which is exactly what you want to have in MAML.

Comment: Actually, the very first answer you got in [github](https://github.com/facebookresearch/higher/issues/30) is exactly about these things. But it is important to note that what is said there about not needing to call `model.zero_grad()` after the inner loop only applicable for the non-MAML case when `copy_model_weights=True` and user of `higher` doesn't want `meta_loss.backward` to propagate to `model.parameters()`. So for the case `copy_model_weights=False` I think `clone` is just done out of extra/unnecessary precaution (in case user somehow start modifying `fnet`'s parameters inplace).

Comment: BTW did you have a chance to play with the toy example here? My hope is that it can help clarify things better than discussions.

Comment: Alex, I think in your sentence " the original model's parameters will actually accumulate gradients if and only if `copy_initial_weights==True`. " you mean `copy_initial_weights==False` because if we have it being true there is a `.detach()` which cuts gradient flows to the original parameters. Is that not right? So MAML needs `copy_initial_weights==False` (and in fact all models that train the initialization of the base model need that to be False).

Comment: I need to head out unfortunately, will try to finish reading the example, but I think now that I understand `.detach()` and `.clone()` more carefully, I think I understand what's going on...my first read to the prose of your answer makes sense to me. Will check carefully soon (hopefully first thing tomorrow) but it seems the main take away is that when we copy in higher it means we don't propagate gradients to the original model (which is weird but fine) and with no copy we do train the initial weights of the model (as in MAML for example).

Comment: Alex, somehow I tried making my own example of your code, pretty trivial, but I get the gradients are `None`. Do you see why? https://gist.github.com/renesax14/d1b119153a3866cff36812c9b218aac6

Comment: That's because you set `track_higher_grads=False` - this is pretty much only supposed to be used at test time (in that mode `higher` is only keeping latest version of inner model parameters and gradients won't propagate anywhere).

Comment: I thought if we had `track_higher_grads=False` then it meant that the gradients were treated as "data" (i.e. we didn't take higher order gradients but did consider the different that they might make in the update rule as data). e.g. see section 3.3.1 from this paper https://openreview.net/pdf?id=rJY0-Kcll it's a very short section.

Comment: they say: "Notice that our formulation would imply that the losses Lt and gradients ∇θt−1Lt of the learner are
dependent on the parameters of the meta-learner. Gradients on the meta-learner’s parameters should
normally take this dependency into account. However, as discussed by Andrychowicz et al. (2016),
this complicates the computation of the meta-learner’s gradients. Thus, following Andrychowicz
et al. (2016), we make the simplifying assumption that these contributions to the gradients aren’t
important and can be ignored, which allows us to avoid taking second derivatives"

Comment: So that flag is not doing that (treating gradients as data)....if it's not then what is it doing?

Comment: Let me copy what the docs say to have it here as reference:
"track_higher_grads – if True, during unrolled optimization the graph be retained, and the fast weights will bear grad funcs, so as to permit backpropagation through the optimization process. Setting this to False allows innerloop_ctx to be used in “test mode”, without potentially tracking higher order gradients. This can be useful when running the training loop at test time, e.g. in k-shot learning experiments, without incurring a significant memory overhead." https://higher.readthedocs.io/en/latest/toplevel.html

Comment: Exactly `this can be ueful when running the training loop at test time`. If you're using `track_higher_grads=False` you just tell higher that you're not planning to do `meta_loss.backward` and it doesn't have to keep all `fnet.parameters(time=T)` except last ones.

Comment: Section 3.3.1 from the article you pointed to still needs to compute `delta_{theta_{t-1}}L_t`. If `track_higher_gradient=False` is set that won't be possible.  The very last step from figure 2 however (test phase) could be done cause they don't need any gradients w.r.t. initial thetas (`theta_T` in their notation).

Comment: I don't get it. Why is this true "Section 3.3.1 from the article you pointed to still needs to compute delta_{theta_{t-1}}L_t. If track_higher_gradient=False is set that won't be possible."? Like if `track_higher_grads=False` then it means the negation of "unrolled optimization the graph be retained, and the fast weights will bear grad funcs". So the fast_weights (I assume those mean `feet.parameters(time=T)`) are not differentiable. Is see why that is bad if we want compute the gradient wrt support set, but what that paper wants is to compute that gradient and have it not propagate further.

Comment: For that I believe they also need `g.detach()` in the my differentiable optimizer implementation if I were to implement it. I sort of implemented a simpler cartoon version of it here: https://gist.github.com/renesax14/8499e0314351ea4199a17e494bff5c4d So I think we **do** need to track the higher gradients but we just need to make sure that we do `g.detach()` to avoid Hessians being computed. Do you agree?

Comment: do you think it's safe to set `copy_initial_weights = True` during meta-testing? Or what should be the value in meta-testing?

Comment: Haven't looked into this library for a while (more than one year), so might be missing something easily. I would imagine you will want to set `track_higher_grads` to `False` for meta-testing in which case it should not be important what `copy_initial_weights` is set to. Overall setting `copy_initial_weights=True` seems ok - it would ensure gradients never go to initial weights of the model which is what you want for meta-testing.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's more or less clear what this means now to me.

First I'd like to make some notation clear, specially with respect to indices wrt inner time step and outer time step (also known as episodes):

```
W^<inner_i, outer_i> = denotes the value a tensor has at time step inner_i, outer_i.
```

At the beginning of training a neural net has params:

```
W^<0,0>
```

and are held inside it's module. For the sake of explanation the specific tensor (for the base model) will be denoted:

```
W = the weight holding the weights for the model. This can be thought as the initialization of the model.
```

and will be updated with with an in-place operation (this is important since `W` is the placeholder for all `W^<0,outer_i>` for all outer step values during "normal" meta-learning) by the outer optimizer. I want to emphasize that `W` is the tensor for the normal Pytorch neural net base model. By changing this in-place with an outer optimizer (like Adam) we are effectively training the initialization. The outer optimizer will use the gradients wrt this tensor to do the update through the whole unrolled inner loop process.

When we say `copy_initial_weights=False` we mean that we will have a gradient path directly to `W` with whatever value it currently has. Usually the context manager is done before a inner loop after an outer step has been done so `W` will have `W^<0,outer_i>` for the current step. In particular the code that does this is [this one](https://github.com/facebookresearch/higher/blob/e45c1a059e39a16fa016d37bc15397824c65547c/higher/patch.py#L526) for `copy_initial_weight=False`:

```
params = [ p.clone() if device is None else p.clone().to(device) for p in module.parameters() ]
```

this might look confusing if you're not familiar with clone but what it's doing is making a copy of the **current weight** of `W`. The unusual thing is that clone also remembers the gradient history from the tensor it came from (`.clone()` is as identity). It's main use it to add an extra layer of safety from the user doing dangerous in-place ops in it's differentiable optimizer. Assuming the user never did anything crazy with in-place ops one could in theory remove the `.clone()`. the reason this is confusing imho is because "copying in Pytorch" (clinging) does **not automatically block gradient flows**, which is what a "real" copy would do (i.e. create a 100% totally separate tensor). This is not what clone does and that is not what `copy_initial_weights` does.

When `copy_initial_weights=True` what really happens is that the weights are **cloned and detached**. See the code it eventually runs ([here](https://github.com/facebookresearch/higher/blob/e45c1a059e39a16fa016d37bc15397824c65547c/higher/utils.py#L136) and [here](https://github.com/facebookresearch/higher/blob/e45c1a059e39a16fa016d37bc15397824c65547c/higher/utils.py#L30)):

```
params = [_copy_tensor(p, safe_copy, device) for p in module.parameters()]
```

which runs copy tensor (assuming they are doing a safe copy i.e. doing the extra clone):

```
 t = t.clone().detach().requires_grad_(t.requires_grad)
```

Note that `.detach()` does not allocate new memory. It shares the memory with the original tensor, which is why the `.clone()` is needed to have this op be "safe" (usually wrt in-place ops).

So when `copy_initial_weights` they are copying and detaching the current value of `W`. This is usually `W^<0,outer_i>` if it's doing usual meta-learning in the inner adaptation loop. So the intended semantics of `copy_initial_weight` is that and the initial_weight they simply mean `W`. The important thing to note is that the intermediate tensors for the net in the inner loop are not denoted in my notation but they are `fmodel.parameters(t=inner_i)`. Also if things are usually meta-learning we have `fmodel.parameters(t=0) = W` and it gets update in-place by the outer optimizer.

Note that because of the outer optimizer's in-place op and the freeing of the graphs we never take the derivate `Grad_{W^<0,0>}` with respect to the initial value of `W`. Which was something I initially thought we were doing.