# How does one implemented a parametrized meta-learner in Pytorch's higher library?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I wanted to implement the meta-lstm meta-learner in the paper [OPTIMIZATION AS A MODEL FOR FEW-SHOT LEARNING](https://openreview.net/pdf?id=rJY0-Kcll) using higher but I found problems. I found that I cannot make it work without removing (what seems to be this crucial line):

https://github.com/facebookresearch/higher/blob/8f0716fb1663218324c02dabdba26b639959cfb6/higher/optim.py#L101

to:

```
#self.param_groups = _copy.deepcopy(other.param_groups)
self.param_groups = other.param_groups
```

I provide an extremely simplified self-contained implementation of something similar here:

https://gist.github.com/renesax14/8499e0314351ea4199a17e494bff5c4d

but I will copy paste here to keep the discussion in one place:

```
# base on the paper "OPTIMIZATION AS A MODEL FOR FEW-SHOT LEARNING": https://openreview.net/pdf?id=rJY0-Kcll

class EmptySimpleMetaLstm(Optimizer):

    def __init__(self, params, trainable_opt_model, trainable_opt_state, *args, **kwargs):
        defaults = {
            'trainable_opt_model':trainable_opt_model, 
            'trainable_opt_state':trainable_opt_state, 
            'args':args, 
            'kwargs':kwargs
        }
        super().__init__(params, defaults)

class SimpleMetaLstm(DifferentiableOptimizer):

    def _update(self, grouped_grads, **kwargs):
        prev_lr = self.param_groups[0]['trainable_opt_state']['prev_lr']
        eta = self.param_groups[0]['trainable_opt_model']['eta']
        # start differentiable & trainable update
        zipped = zip(self.param_groups, grouped_grads)
        for group_idx, (group, grads) in enumerate(zipped):
            for p_idx, (p, g) in enumerate(zip(group['params'], grads)):
                if g is None:
                    continue
                # get gradient as "data"
                g = g.detach() # gradients of gradients are not used (no hessians)
                ## very simplified version of meta-lstm meta-learner
                input_metalstm = torch.stack([p, g, prev_lr.view(1,1)]).view(1,3) # [p, g, prev_lr] note it's missing loss, normalization etc. see original paper
                lr = eta(input_metalstm).view(1)
                fg = 1 - lr # learnable forget rate
                ## update suggested by meta-lstm meta-learner
                p_new = fg*p - lr*g
                group['params'][p_idx] = p_new
        # fake returns
        self.param_groups[0]['trainable_opt_state']['prev_lr'] = lr

higher.register_optim(EmptySimpleMetaLstm, SimpleMetaLstm)

def test_parametrized_inner_optimizer():
    import torch
    import torch.nn as nn
    import torch.optim as optim
    from collections import OrderedDict

    ## training config
    #device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
    track_higher_grads = True # if True, during unrolled optimization the graph be retained, and the fast weights will bear grad funcs, so as to permit backpropagation through the optimization process. False during test time for efficiency reasons
    copy_initial_weights = False # if False then we train the base models initial weights (i.e. the base model's initialization)
    episodes = 5
    nb_inner_train_steps = 5
    ## get base model
    base_mdl = nn.Sequential(OrderedDict([
        ('fc', nn.Linear(1,1, bias=False)),
        ('relu', nn.ReLU())
        ]))
    ## parametrization/mdl for the inner optimizer
    opt_mdl = nn.Sequential(OrderedDict([
        ('fc', nn.Linear(3,1, bias=False)), # 3 inputs 1 for parameter, 1 for gradient, 1 for previous lr
        ('sigmoid', nn.Sigmoid())
        ]))
    ## get outer optimizer (not differentiable nor trainable)
    outer_opt = optim.Adam([{'params': base_mdl.parameters()},{'params': opt_mdl.parameters()}], lr=0.01)
    for episode in range(episodes):
        ## get fake support & query data (from a single task and 1 data point)
        spt_x, spt_y, qry_x, qry_y = torch.randn(1), torch.randn(1), torch.randn(1), torch.randn(1)
        ## get differentiable & trainable (parametrized) inner optimizer
        inner_opt = EmptySimpleMetaLstm(base_mdl.parameters(), trainable_opt_model={'eta': opt_mdl}, trainable_opt_state={'prev_lr': 0.9*torch.randn(1)})
        with higher.innerloop_ctx(base_mdl, inner_opt, copy_initial_weights=copy_initial_weights, track_higher_grads=track_higher_grads) as (fmodel, diffopt):
            for i_inner in range(nb_inner_train_steps): # this current version implements full gradient descent on k_shot examples (which is usually small  5)
                fmodel.train()
                # base/child model forward pass
                inner_loss = 0.5*((fmodel(spt_x) - spt_y))**2
                # inner-opt update
                diffopt.step(inner_loss)
            ## Evaluate on query set for current task
            qry_loss = 0.5*((fmodel(qry_x) - qry_y))**2
            qry_loss.backward() # for memory efficient computation
        ## outer update
        print(f'episode = {episode}')
        print(f'base_mdl.grad = {base_mdl.fc.weight.grad}')
        print(f'opt_mdl.grad = {opt_mdl.fc.weight.grad}')
        outer_opt.step()
        outer_opt.zero_grad()
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_parametrized_inner_optimizer()
    print('Done \a')

"""
output when deep copy is uncommented (parametrized optimizer trains properly):
episode = 0
base_mdl.grad = tensor([[-0.0351]])
opt_mdl.grad = tensor([[0.0085, 0.0000, 0.0204]])
episode = 1
base_mdl.grad = tensor([[0.0311]])
opt_mdl.grad = tensor([[-0.0086, -0.0100,  0.0358]])
episode = 2
base_mdl.grad = tensor([[0.]])
opt_mdl.grad = tensor([[0., 0., 0.]])
episode = 3
base_mdl.grad = tensor([[0.0066]])
opt_mdl.grad = tensor([[-0.0016,  0.0000, -0.0032]])
episode = 4
base_mdl.grad = tensor([[-0.0311]])
opt_mdl.grad = tensor([[0.0077, 0.0000, 0.0130]])
Done 
when deep copy is on (paremeters of inner optimizer are not train, sad!):
episode = 0
base_mdl.grad = tensor([[0.]])
opt_mdl.grad = None
episode = 1
base_mdl.grad = tensor([[0.]])
opt_mdl.grad = None
episode = 2
base_mdl.grad = tensor([[0.0069]])
opt_mdl.grad = None
episode = 3
base_mdl.grad = tensor([[0.]])
opt_mdl.grad = None
episode = 4
base_mdl.grad = tensor([[0.]])
opt_mdl.grad = None
Done
The deep copy line in higher I am referencing:
        self.param_groups = _copy.deepcopy(other.param_groups)
        #self.param_groups = other.param_groups
"""
```

---

## Real Solution

The real solution is if I could pass an arbitrary dictionary to a differentiable optimizer and if I could do whatever I wanted with it.

---

## update:

perhaps this can be implemented with override:

> override (optional) – a dictionary mapping optimizer settings (i.e. those which would be passed to the optimizer constructor or provided within parameter groups) to either singleton lists of override values, or to a list of override values of length equal to the number of parameter groups. If a single override is provided for a keyword, it is used for all parameter groups. If a list is provided, the ith element of the list overrides the corresponding setting in the ith parameter group. This permits the passing of tensors requiring gradient to differentiable optimizers for use as optimizer settings.

Didn't work with override:

```
Exception has occurred: ValueError 
Mismatch between the number of override tensors for optimizer parameter trainable_opt_model and the number of parameter groups.
seems like it checks that these lengths match... 

def _apply_override(self, override: _OverrideType) -> None: 
for k, v in override.items(): 
# Sanity check 
if (len(v) != 1) and (len(v) != len(self.param_groups)
```

---

I think this is all I need:

```
inner_opt = EmptySimpleMetaLstm( base_mdl.parameters() )
with higher.innerloop_ctx(base_mdl, inner_opt, copy_initial_weights=copy_initial_weights, track_higher_grads=track_higher_grads) as (fmodel, diffopt):
     diffopt.override = {'trainable_opt_model': opt_mdl, 'trainable_opt_state': {'prev_lr': 0.9*torch.randn(1)} }
```

---

cross-posted:

- git issue in higher: https://github.com/facebookresearch/higher/issues/62
- https://www.reddit.com/r/pytorch/comments/hbp1n5/how_does_one_implemented_a_parametrized/?
- https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-does-one-implemented-a-parametrized-meta-learner-in-pytorchs-higher-library/85988

related:

- [Why does higher need to deep copy the parameters of the base model to create a functional model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62437960/why-does-higher-need-to-deep-copy-the-parameters-of-the-base-model-to-create-a-f/62438602?noredirect=1#comment110458561_62438602)
- [What does the copy_initial_weights documentation mean in the higher library for Pytorch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60311183/what-does-the-copy-initial-weights-documentation-mean-in-the-higher-library-for/62378264?noredirect=1#comment110457791_62378264)

Comment: note implementing meta-lstm (like meta-learner) is just an simple example. I want to be able to have a general update rule that could be implemented by a Neural Network. e.g. `w := w + NN(g,w,loss,...)` or `w := NN(g,w,loss,...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure this is what you want, but if you can express the inner loop training as a sequence of, say SGD (or another simple optimizer) updates with parameters such as `lr` being computed by a NN you want to train (e.g. LSTM) then you can just pass `override` to innerloop optimizer with every call of `diffopt.step`. Here is a toy example:

```
def test_parametrized_inner_optimizer():
    import torch
    import torch.nn as nn
    import torch.optim as optim
    from collections import OrderedDict
    import higher

    ## training config
    #device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
    track_higher_grads = True # if True, during unrolled optimization the graph be retained, and the fast weights will bear grad funcs, so as to permit backpropagation through the optimization process. False during test time for efficiency reasons
    copy_initial_weights = False # if False then we train the base models initial weights (i.e. the base model's initialization)
    episodes = 5
    nb_inner_train_steps = 5
    ## get base model
    base_mdl = nn.Sequential(OrderedDict([
        ('fc', nn.Linear(1,1, bias=False)),
        ('relu', nn.LeakyReLU()) # using LeakyReLU here otherwise too often getting 0 gradients on everything :) 
        ]))
    ## parametrization/mdl for the inner optimizer
    opt_mdl = nn.Sequential(OrderedDict([
        ('fc', nn.Linear(3,1, bias=False)), # 3 inputs [p, g, prev_lr] 1 for parameter, 1 for gradient, 1 for previous lr
        ('sigmoid', nn.Sigmoid())
        ]))
    ##
    par = torch.tensor([0.2], requires_grad=True) # is that what you mean by parameters?

    ## get outer optimizer (not differentiable nor trainable)
    outer_opt = optim.Adam([{'params': base_mdl.parameters()},{'params': opt_mdl.parameters()}], lr=0.01)
    for episode in range(episodes):
        ## get fake support & query data (from a single task and 1 data point)
        spt_x, spt_y, qry_x, qry_y = torch.randn(1), torch.randn(1), torch.randn(1), torch.randn(1)
        ## get differentiable reference optimizer
        inner_opt = torch.optim.SGD(base_mdl.parameters(), lr=0.1) # lr will be overriden
        with higher.innerloop_ctx(base_mdl, inner_opt, copy_initial_weights=copy_initial_weights, track_higher_grads=track_higher_grads) as (fmodel, diffopt):
            prev_lr = torch.tensor([0.1]) # or whatever supposed to be used at first step as prev_lr input for opt_mdl
            for i_inner in range(nb_inner_train_steps): # this current version implements full gradient descent on k_shot examples (which is usually small  5)
                fmodel.train()
                # base/child model forward pass
                inner_loss = 0.5*((fmodel(spt_x) - spt_y))**2

                # latest_grad is same thing as the one we will use for inner optimizer step, but we
                # need it before the step because we will also produce lr based on it using opt_mdl
                latest_grad = torch.autograd.grad(
                        inner_loss, fmodel.parameters(), retain_graph=True, create_graph=True) # create_graph makes the gradient returned not just separate tensor, but something gradients can propagate through
                latest_grad = latest_grad[0].reshape(-1)

                # inner-opt update
                lr_as_output_of_another_model_can_be_lstm_or_whatever = opt_mdl(torch.stack((par, latest_grad, prev_lr)).reshape(1, -1))[0]
                diffopt.step(inner_loss, override={'lr': lr_as_output_of_another_model_can_be_lstm_or_whatever})
                prev_lr = lr_as_output_of_another_model_can_be_lstm_or_whatever
            ## Evaluate on query set for current task
            qry_loss = 0.5*((fmodel(qry_x) - qry_y))**2
            qry_loss.backward() # for memory efficient computation
        ## outer update
        print(f'episode = {episode}')
        print(f'base_mdl.grad = {base_mdl.fc.weight.grad}')
        print(f'opt_mdl.grad = {opt_mdl.fc.weight.grad}')
        outer_opt.step()
        outer_opt.zero_grad()

test_parametrized_inner_optimizer()
```

Notice the use of `create_graph=True` in addition to `retain_graph=True` when applying `torch.autograd.grad`. If we don't do that then we wouldn't propagate gradients through gradient-input to NN which computes lr here (referenced article's paragraph 3.3.1 suggests to simplify computation and not propagate gradients there, but here the choice can be made by either providing `create_graph=True` or not doing so).

Comment: hmmm...but how do you implement the forget gate from the meta-lstm paper? the update rule is `w:= f*p - lr*g` and in my simplified example I did `f = 1 - lr` but in general it could be a NN. Honestly, what I am trying to have is that it's general enough to implement an update step entirely by a NN e.g. `w := w + NN(p, g, loss, ...)` or `w := NN(p, g, loss, ...)`. I don't think that can be done with override. Did you have time to check my suggestion where after the creation of `diffop` I immediately create a field in diffop with the dictionary containing any info I want `diffop.dict = dict`?

Comment: I have to be sincere, I am still unsure about what section 3.3.1 means. I thought that `g = g.detach()` in the update step of the differentiable optimizer should be sufficient. Is it not? If not why not? Thanks for the help Alex!

Comment: What exactly are `f` and `p`? `g` is the gradient and `lr` here is previous lr? Or constant? Regarding section 3.3.1 - if you don't use `create_graph=True` it is similar to doing `g.detach()` - thing is `g` won't have a graph to propagate gradient by default if you didn't ask pytorch to create it by `create_graph=True`. So you either should create gradient if you want to propagate through g, or just don't use `create_graph=True` and then there will be no need in `g.detach()`.

Comment: If you look at my suggested implementation in the differentiable optimizer for simple meta-lstm meta-learner, the differentiable update is `p = fg*p - lr*g` where `lr = NN(p, g, loss, prev_lr)` and `fg = 1 - lr ` for simplicity. Thus `lr` is the current lr suggested by the meta-learner and `fg` is the current forget rate suggested by the (simplified) meta-learner and `g` is the current gradients of the learner wrt support set/train set that does not allow gradients to propagate according to my understanding of section 3.3.1 (thus using `g.detach()`.

Comment: So `p` is a trainable weight from inner loop model's weights?

Comment: My main trick to give access to the update function in the DifferentiableOptimizer is the use of `diffopt.override = {opt_mdl, ... anything I need ...}` so that that field exists once the `diffopt.step(inner_loss)` is done and thus it has access to the `opt_mdl` (or anything else I want to pass to it).

Comment: Yes, `p` is the fast weights inside the `_update` step the the user implements when implanting his/her differentiable optimizer. So in my above code you can explicitly see it and it comes from the for loop `for p_idx, (p, g) in enumerate(zip(group['params'], grads)):` Does that clarify things?

Comment: Yes, that clarifies things. And also important thing here is that your `lr=NN(p, g, loss, prev_lr)` really means individual `lr` and `prev_lr` for each weight of fast model. Is that correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216294/discussion-between-pinocchio-and-alexander-pivovarov).